# AsyncMiddleware handler in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have read promise/resolve/reject as well as async/await.

I want to handle async/await error and found a code on [medium.com](https://medium.com/@Abazhenov/using-async-await-in-express-with-node-8-b8af872c0016) but I am not able to understand what exactly it does.

Can anyone please try to explain how below code works:

a) what is `fn` here?

b) I actually can't understand any code from the below block.

```
const asyncMiddleware = fn =>
  (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
      .catch(next);
  };
```

And using it as below:

```
router.get('/users/:id', asyncMiddleware(async (req, res, next) => {
    /* 
      if there is an error thrown in getUserFromDb, asyncMiddleware
      will pass it to next() and express will handle the error;
    */
    const user = await getUserFromDb({ id: req.params.id })
    res.json(user);
}));
```

Comment: `fn` is just the function your passing to `asyncMiddleware`..   Think of `asyncMiddleware` as a wrapper function, it calls your code and handles the errors.

Answer (score 0):

It the same as:

```
// asyncMiddleware is function that returns another function
const asyncMiddleware = function(fn){
  return (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next))
      .catch(next);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just ES6 syntax. Try to read about how things are written in ES6.
fn is a function which is being given as a argument to asyncMiddleware function. The fn function returns a promise which is being resolved in the line 
Promise.resolve(fn(req, res, next)).if any error is encountered in fn, it will go to catch and error is handled.

Hope it helps you.